# State not updating in useEffects

Tags: reactjs

Currently i am passing local stored user details to hooks variable inside useEffect. i can get the data from local storage but same values are not passing to hooks variable. i want this value to be update in state when component mount. i checked using console.log and data passing to variable from localStorage

```
[function App() {
const [usercred , setUsercred] = useState({
  id:'',
  display : '',
  picture : '',
  token : '',
  isAuthenticated : false
});
  
  useEffect(() =>{
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    setUsercred({id:user.id,
      display : user.display,
      picture: user.picture,
      token : user.token,
      isAuthenticated : true
    });
    console.log("Below data from 'user'")
    console.log(user);

    console.log("Below data from Hooks Variable")
    console.log(usercred);
  },[])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: If you want to initialize a state of the `useState` hook you should use the initializer of that hook: `const [state, setState] = useState(() => tryReadLocalStorage('user'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you check is not correct.
When you do `console.log(usercred);` inside useEffect function, the state variable `usercred` will be updated in the next render.
For example, if you put `usercred` in the dom

```
<div>{usercred.isAuthenticated}</div>
```

you will see it changing.

Comment: Thanks! its just as u said. when passing down to props i can see the data